# error occured while linking abaqus2018 with vs2016 and ps2012

Tags: fortran, subroutine, weld, abaqus

I have a problem in linking the abaqus 2018 with the visual studios 2012 and parallel studios 2016.... the error refers that"Problem during compilation - C:\Circulr weld\arcweld.for"..this was one of the problems when the job was running in abaqus...then i changed the code for the respective file then the error was different..."Problem during linking - Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines.   This error may be due to a mismatch in the Abaqus user subroutine arguments.   These arguments sometimes change from release to release, so user subroutines   used with a previous release of Abaqus may need to be adjusted"....what should i do now for this ...how do i run the programe???

I have already tried parallel studios 2019 and other versions of visual studios

The result should be of welding the pipes by using arc welding method ...It's the simulation of welding process which is shown by the movement of the heat flux source...the process in the abaqus are over only on linking the fortran code file to the Abaqus-Dflux subroutine is difficult.

Comment: show us the minimal example of your code that does not work. Then maybe we can help. The error you describe can also result in errors in your code.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading all environment variables? In Windows, there should be an Intel cmd.exe equivalent that loads it automatically; otherwise you must load all variables through the appropriate system and configuration. Perhaps sharing the complete output from the interactive console would help.